# dlib.image_window.add_overlay() does not show closed figure of partial face landmarks

Tags: python-3.x, dlib

I am trying to display landmark points 48-67 that form the jaw region of 68-landmark face object.
The image_window 's method in use has the following signature-
add_overlay(dlib.full_object_detection)

I am extracting dlib.points 48-67 from shape_predictor returned full_object_detection object this way - :

```
faces = faceDetector(img,1)
lipPoints = []
shape = detector(img,faces[0])
for i in range(48,68):
    lipPoints.append(shape.part(i))
lipDetections = dlib.full_object_detection(faces[0],lipPoints)
win.add_overlay(lipDetections)
```

But it results in isolated points of jaws instead of closed curve-

[image]

When I use all 68 points by setting range(0,68), the image_window shows all points connected to describe the face.

```
faces = faceDetector(img,1)
lipPoints = []
shape = detector(img,faces[0])
for i in range(0,68):
    lipPoints.append(shape.part(i))
lipDetections = dlib.full_object_detection(faces[0],lipPoints)
win.add_overlay(lipDetections)
```

The code outputs curves instead of point indices as expected-

[image]

How does add_overlay() method behave differently even after using the same overload of same instance of image_window? The full_object_detector is created in the same manner in both situations so I expected it to show show a closed figure of lip boundaries.

I looked at the source code for add_overlay(full_object_detection) but did not find anything that shows any link between add_overlay with detector model. How do I display connected points of jaws only?

I have also tried training dlib.shape_predictor() myself using only jaw landmarks by removing other landmarks from train xml file but the results are same, no closed curve, only isolated points are displayed.

I am using dlib v19.15, installed from source on Ubuntu 18.04. @davis-king can you help?